# How to get all emails and messages from social media into Android Studio Application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, project

I am making a Ticketing Manager App. I have to collect all the queries asked on website, through mail, through social media and get it into my android app. Please help.

Comment: what research have you done so far? what have you tried? we aren't here to do your projects for you

Comment: What are "queries" in this case? Customer enquiries? Database queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to collect all the queries asked on website, through mail, through social media and get it into my android app

**For website**, The website must have an API

**For mail**, You can use GMAIL API if it's gmail.

**For social media**, The social site must have its own API.